# Built-in mod ('%') vs custom mod function: improve the performance of modulus operation

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, modulo, modular-arithmetic

Recently I came to know that the mod('%') operator is very slow. So I made a function which will work just like a%b. But is it faster than the mod operator?

Here's my function

```
int mod(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp = a/b;
    return a - (b*tmp);
}
```

Comment: Do your own benchmarking, but you're not going to do better than the compiler.

Comment: hmm both method works equally fast... even sometimes manual mod is faster!

Comment: 'I came to know that the mod('%') operator is very slow' - really?  How do you measure that, and what are you comparing against?

Comment: First, generate assembly language output and verify that there is no function call generated.  You will loose the contest if the compiler emits assembly instructions without any branch and return instructions.

Comment: By the way, some processors have instructions that can return both the quotient and the remainder of a division with one instruction.

Comment: ^^^^ it's one 'div' call on many processors.

Comment: Example x86:  'F7 /6, DIV r/m32, Unsigned divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result stored in EAX = Quotient, EDX = Remainder.

Comment: Or, for ints, :'F7 /7, IDIV r/m32  Signed divide EDX:EAX by r/m32, with result stored in EAX = Quotient, EDX = Remainder.

Comment: I compared against other mathematical operator such as +/-. This operator can not do what mod can but work very fast. @ Martin James

Comment: DCV  - sorry another user ratted this out as being homework/competition entry and you are conning SO contributors.

Comment: Just because the processor can do it in one instruction (e.g. DIV) does not mean it executes in one clock cycle.  division and modulo take more than clock cycle. Typically division takes 1 clock cycle per bit, x86 can do it a bit faster because of black magic, but it is still an order of magnitude slower than addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [Chandler Carruth's benchmarks at CppCon 2015](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk?t=56m34s), the fastest modulo operator *(on x86, when compiled with Clang)* is:

```
int fast_mod(const int input, const int ceil) {
    // apply the modulo operator only when needed
    // (i.e. when the input is greater than the ceiling)
    return input >= ceil ? input % ceil : input;
    // NB: the assumption here is that the numbers are positive
}
```

I suggest that you watch the whole talk, he goes into more details on why this method is faster than just using `%` unconditionally.

Comment: AFAIK Chandler Carruth works on compiler construction. I understand his talk, that he tries to explain, how compiler builders find and handle improved optimizations. Resisting the temptation to make your hand crufted "optimized" implementations of fundamental stuff will help you to profit from that work as soon as the compiler has it - and of course all the optimizations you did not come up with as well. Note: I did not say "don't optimize", but "resist micro optimizations".

Comment: I haven't watched the video either, but `fast_mod` seems broken for negative input: `-5 % 5 == 0` but `fast_mod(-5, 5) == -5`.

Comment: Yes. As mentioned in the last comment: _"NB: the assumption here is that the numbers are positive"_. (by _"numbers"_, I meant `input` and `ceil`)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see this. Still it seems worth pointing out that the optimization only works for a very special case. C's `%` is defined not only for `int` and not only for positive numbers.

Comment: whether this is good or not depends on the distribution of values for `input`. I find it mostly good when one needs to have a wrapping counter.

Answer (score 10):

This will likely be compiler and platform dependent.

But I was interested and on my system you appear to be correct in my benchmarks. However the method from [@865719's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33333636/3303195) is fastest:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Timer
{
    using clk = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using microseconds = std::chrono::microseconds;

    clk::time_point tsb;
    clk::time_point tse;

public:

    void clear() { tsb = tse = clk::now(); }
    void start() { tsb = clk::now(); }
    void stop() { tse = clk::now(); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Timer& timer)
    {
        return o << timer.secs();
    }

    // return time difference in seconds
    double secs() const
    {
        if(tse <= tsb)
            return 0.0;
        auto d = std::chrono::duration_cast<microseconds>(tse - tsb);
        return d.count() / 1000000.0;
    }
};

int mod(int a, int b)
{
    int tmp=a/b;
    return a-(b*tmp);
}

int fast_mod(const int input, const int ceil) {
    // apply the modulo operator only when needed
    // (i.e. when the input is greater than the ceiling)
    return input < ceil ? input : input % ceil;
    // NB: the assumption here is that the numbers are positive
}

int main()
{
    auto N = 1000000000U;
    unsigned sum = 0;

    Timer timer;

    for(auto times = 0U; times < 3; ++times)
    {
        std::cout << "     run: " << (times + 1) << '\n';

        sum = 0;
        timer.start();
        for(decltype(N) n = 0; n < N; ++n)
            sum += n % (N - n);
        timer.stop();

        std::cout << "       %: " << sum << " " << timer << "s" << '\n';

        sum = 0;
        timer.start();
        for(decltype(N) n = 0; n < N; ++n)
            sum += mod(n, N - n);
        timer.stop();

        std::cout << "     mod: " << sum << " " << timer << "s" << '\n';

        sum = 0;
        timer.start();
        for(decltype(N) n = 0; n < N; ++n)
            sum += fast_mod(n, N - n);
        timer.stop();

        std::cout << "fast_mod: " << sum << " " << timer << "s" << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Build:** `GCC 5.1.1` (x86_64)

```
g++ -std=c++14 -march=native -O3 -g0 ...
```

**Output:**

```
     run: 1
       %: 3081207628 5.49396s
     mod: 3081207628 4.30814s
fast_mod: 3081207628 2.51296s
     run: 2
       %: 3081207628 5.5522s
     mod: 3081207628 4.25427s
fast_mod: 3081207628 2.52364s
     run: 3
       %: 3081207628 5.4947s
     mod: 3081207628 4.29646s
fast_mod: 3081207628 2.56916s
```

Comment: What compiler flags did you use?

Comment: @black I added build info to the answer.

Comment: @Galik My compiler can not compile your code. anyway can you use this new mod function and tell me the time please?                               int mod(int a, int b)
{
    //int tmp=a/b;
    return a>b?a-(b*(a/b)):a;
}

Comment: @madMDT You need to tuen on `C++11` to compile the code. In my tests your new function is about the same as `fast_mod`.

Comment: This performance test might return very unprecise results. I would not trust them for making conclusions on how the calculations fare in real world examples.

Comment: I tried both modulus and your function fast_mod function for factoring 1 trillion. The modulus operator averaged 1.9 seconds. The fast_mod function averaged 3.7 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

It is often possible for a programmer to beat the performance of the remainder operation in cases where a programmer knows things about the operands that the compiler doesn't.  For example, if the base is likely to be a power of 2, but
is not particularly likely to be larger than the value to be reduced, one could
use something like:

```
unsigned mod(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  return y & (y-1) ? x % y : x & (y-1);
}
```

If the compiler expands the function in-line and the base is a constant
power of 2, the compiler will replace the remainder operator with a bitwise
AND, which is apt to be a major improvement.  In cases where the base isn't
a constant power of two, the generated code would need to do a little bit
of computation before selecting whether to use the remainder operator, but
in cases where the base happens to be a power of two the cost savings of
the bitwise AND may exceed the cost of the conditional logic.

Another scenario where a custom modulus function may help is when the base
is a fixed constant for which the compiler hasn't made provisions to compute
the remainder.  For example, if one wants to compute x % 65521 on a platform
which can perform rapid integer shifts and multiplies, one may observe that computing `x -= (x>>16)*65521;` will cause `x` to be much smaller but will not affect the value of `x % 65521`.  Doing the operation a second time will reduce `x` to the range 0..65745--small enough that a single conditional subtraction will yield the correct remainder.

Some compilers may know how to use such techniques to handle the `%` operator efficiently with a constant base, but for those that don't the approach can be a useful optimization, especially when dealing with numbers larger than a machine word [observe that 65521 is 65536-15, so on a 16-bit machine one could evaluate `x` as `x = (x & 65535) + 15*(x >> 16)`.  Not as readable as the form which subtracts `65521 * (x >> 16)`, but it's easy to see how it could be handled efficiently on a 16-bit machine.

Comment: Return type `unsigned` ? Never seen before by me and compilers.

Comment: @AkibAzmain: Huh?  It's equivalent to `unsigned int`, and I've seen it a lot more often than the longer form.

Answer (score 1):

Just contributing a little bit with this discussion. If you want to handle negative numbers, use the following function:

```
inline long long mod(const long long x, const long long y) {
    if (x >= y) {
        return x % y;
    } else if (x < 0) {
        return (x % y + y) % y;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware of taking negative numbers (mod p). In many programming languages, ((−2)%5)!=(3%5). Thus you can compute the same hash values for two strings, but when you compare them, they appear to be different. To avoid this issue, you can use such construct in the code: x ← ((a%p)+p)%p instead of just x ← a%p

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, your micro optimized code will not beat the compiler. I also don't know where that "wisdom" comes from, that claims the built in `%` to be slow. It is just as fast as the machine will be able to calculate it - with all the micro optimizations the compiler can do for you.

Also note, that performance measurements of such very small pieces of code is not an easy task. Conditionals of a loop construct or the jitter of your time measurement might dominate your results. You can find some talks on such issues by people like e.g. Andrei Alexantrescu, or Chandler Caruth on youtube. I have once written a micro benchmarking framework for a project I was working on. There is really a lot to care about, including external stuff like the OS preempting your thread, or moving it to another core.

Comment: Do you ever tried running it? I ran it on my pc several times and then asked this question. I dont know why mod(%) is slow but combination of subtraction(-) and division(/) works a very little bit faster.

Comment: @madMDT well, then your compiler vendor should probably use your implementation instead of a naive one, or even better Chandlers. I'd expect the next version of clang to do so, because that is, what Chandler is working on.