# Why is iterating though `std::vector` faster than iterating though `std::array`?

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking

I recently asked this question:
[Why is iterating an std::array much faster than iterating an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124571/why-is-iterating-an-stdarray-much-faster-than-iterating-an-stdvector)

As people quickly pointed out, my benchmark had many flaws. So as I was trying to fix my benchmark, I noticed that `std::vector` wasn't slower than `std::array` and, in fact, it was quite the opposite.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

constexpr int n = 100'000'000;
vector<int> v(n);
//array<int, n> v;

int main()
{
    int res = 0;
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int x : v)
        res += x;
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto diff = end - start;
    double elapsed =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<
            std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>
        >(end - start).count();
    printf("result: %d\ntime: %f\n", res, elapsed);
}
```

Things I've tried to improve from my previous benchmark:

- Made sure I'm using the result, so the whole loop is not optimized away
- Using `-O3` flag for speed
- Use `std::chrono` instead of the `time` command. That's so we can isolate the part we want to measure (just the for loop). Static initialization of variables and things like that won't be measured.

The measured times:

array:

```
$ g++ arrVsVec.cpp -O3
$ ./a.out
result: 0
time: 99.554109
```

vector:

```
$ g++ arrVsVec.cpp -O3
$ ./a.out
result: 0
time: 30.734491
```

I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong this time.

[Watch the disassembly in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VcwI1m)

Comment: It is very likely that dynamic allocation had the result of "priming" the memory pages that comprise the storage of the vector. The array is "stored" in the uninitialized memory, that gets demand paged-in, so iterating over the array generates page-faults that require the OS to go through the motions of allocating and clearing the underlying memory pages. Create a second loop, right after the first one, and then time the second loop instead of the first one. Better yet: move the first loop into a separate function in a different translation unit, and call it before the second loop.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's very interesting. I will try that

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Indeed, the second loop was 10 times faster for `std::array`. There was no improvement for `std::vector`

Comment: Now move the first loop into an external function, that gets compiled separately. The compiler might still be up to some optimization tricks.

Comment: You might try comparing with a heap-allocated `std::array` as in `auto pv = std::make_unique<std::array<int, n>>(); auto& v = *pv;`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Amazing, now both take the same time. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Ben Yep, they have the same performance :)

Comment: The differences you've run into (before compensating for them) demonstrate how amazing compilers optimization is these days.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: dynamic allocation is still lazy, what's going on is that std::vector *initializes* the memory by writing `0` with the default constructor for `int`.  If you'd used `new int[n]` to just dynamically allocate without touching the memory, you'd still get soft page faults and TLB misses.  (Assuming you still do that at global scope, so the compiler can't see that it's definitely reading uninitialized memory: UB it could optimize away.)

Comment: @Eljay Sometimes. But if you think about it, it was optimizing something for the `array` case but not for the `vector`case. And just changing things a bit was enough to turn off those optimizations

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, just tried it and seem to be true

Comment: @Eljay huh?  No, the std::vector version is just doing a bunch of work before `main` runs, allocating and writing all the memory to do all the page faults outside the timed region.  This isn't compiler optimization, it's just timing error.  If you timed the entire program, the `std::vector` version would probably be slower because it's first writing and *then* reading, instead of just reading from the BSS.  (You get page faults that CoW map those BSS pages to the same physical zero page, so you get TLB misses + page faults but mostly data-cache hits.)

Comment: partial duplicate: [Can static memory be lazily allocated?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50901873).  I'm sure I've seen or written an answer to this question before, still looking for a more detailed duplicate about lazy BSS allocation leading to page-faults inside the timed region.

Comment: The array is not zero initialized so maybe the addition the loop can't be optimized away

Comment: @Galik `array` is zero-initialized, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: but code-gen for `main` doesn't know that unless maybe you compile with `gcc -fwhole-program`.  It's a non-`const` global so anything else could have modified it after static initialization, before `main` or  inside any non-inline function call like `chrono::steady_clock::now`.  (GCC doesn't have a builtin for `now()` so it just has to treat it like any non-inline function that might modify any global.)  Anyway, these things are true for both the vector and the array. https://godbolt.org/z/JT9u6B shows that printing the sum stops it from optimizing away like in OP's prev Q.

Comment: I'm not a mind reader but I think the OP's question was not specific to this specific case where `array` and `vector` have static storage (not really true for `vector`). @PeterCordes comment explain clearly that a bunch of things happen *before* the part of the code we are timing. This highlights the fact that we should always perform a *dry run* before actually timing, or at least time many runs in order to amortise such peripheral costs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is due to memory pages of `array` not being resident in process address space (global scope array is stored in [`.bss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) section of the executable that hasn't been paged in, [it is zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables)). Whereas `vector` has just been allocated and zero-filled, so its memory pages are already present.

If you add

```
std::fill_n(v.data(), n, 1); // included in <algorithm>
```

as the first line of `main` to bring the pages in (pre-fault), that makes `array` time the same as that of `vector`.

---

On Linux, instead of that, you can do `mlock(v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(v[0]));` to bring the pages into the address space. See [`man mlock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) for full details.

Comment: Or you could make array possibly faster than vector by only reading it with a warm-up loop instead of writing it, so the pages can stay CoW mapped to the same physical zero page.  Then you can get L1d or L2 hits while looping over the huge array, and only some possible TLB misses depending on the microarchitecture.

Comment: @PeterCordes After the write loop the pages are resident and its cached parts are valid. I do not see how reading instead of writing would change things, since the timing is done after that loop.

Comment: related: [Global variable seems to not occupy any memory space](//stackoverflow.com/q/12148967)  and [Can static memory be lazily allocated?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50901873).  Especially [Why is the second loop over a static array in the BSS faster than the first?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24376732) is specifically about a large static array, and the first loop eating all the page faults as a warm-up for the 2nd loop.

Comment: [Why is adding two std::vectors slower than raw arrays from new\[\]?](//stackoverflow.com/a/44330141) is very good, this Q is a possible duplicate.  (Except for the non-obvious fact that untouched BSS storage is basically like untouched memory from `new`)

Comment: writing forces allocation of separate physical pages for each virtual page (CoW).  Reading can allow all the virtual pages of the array to still share the same physical page.  The logical array size is larger than L1d, L2, or even L3 cache sizes (100M * 4 bytes) so they *won't* still be hot after an init loop over the whole array.  Data has to come from DRAM.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is `.bss` section, it is not backed by pages in the executable image, so its pages are always CoW, aren't they? Oh, you probably mean that it uses the same read-only zero page for the entire `.bss` section. I see now, said a blind man.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  My understanding / mental-model is that there is a single physical 4k and/or 2M zero page that Linux uses for *every* known-zero-backed anonymous page across all processes / tasks.  Any mapping of it is of course read-only.  A read fault on an anonymous page just sets up this read-only CoW mapping, instead of preparing for a write.

Comment: @PeterCordes On the other hand, IIRC, in AMD CPU documentation it talks about cache line tagging and specifically mentions that when the same hardware page is mapped multiple times in the same address space, that may result in a different cache line tag, hence resulting in cache miss, although the page is in cache.

Comment: Bulldozer L1d cache is VIPT (virtually-indexed / physically-tagged), according to https://www.realworldtech.com/bulldozer/8/.  16kiB / 4-way is small enough that it doesn't need anything special to avoid aliasing problems, Like Intel's and Ryzens's 32kiB / 8-way.  I haven't checked AMD's optimization manual, but perhaps what you're remembering is for AMD K10 (Barcelona/Istanbul) which used a 64kiB / 2-way associative L1d cache and would need special tricks to avoid aliasing if it wants to be VIPT (to allow indexing in parallel with TLB).  IDK, it's possible that BD or Zen does something.

Comment: On my Skylake, I see a significant number of L2 hits when looping repeatedly over the unwritten array.   https://godbolt.org/z/SxI2_j (I checked the asm to make sure my tricks stopped the repeat-loop from optimizing away).  I used `taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u,mem_load_retired.l2_miss:u,mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u -r4 ./touchpage-array-readinit-O3-native`.  I see only 808 page faults, so going read-only also encouraged more faultaround, or hugepages?

Comment: @PeterCordes [AMD Software Optimization Guide for Zen CPU](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/55723_SOG_Fam_17h_Processors_3.00.pdf): _Linear aliasing occurs when two different linear addresses are mapped to the same physical address. This can cause performance penalties for loads and stores to the aliased cachelines. A load to an address that is valid in the L1 DC but under a different linear alias will see an L1 DC miss, which requires an L2 cache request to be made. The latency will generally be no larger than that of an L2 cache hit._

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  IDK why they do that.  I think on Intel my L2 cache hits were only due to prefetch from L3.  I think Linux might have been using a 2M transparent hugepage for the unwritten BSS because I still get some L2 misses but no L3 misses.  Read-init makes the read loop about 2.8x faster than write-init where the read loop *does* get some L3 misses, and more TLB misses.  Also more page faults.  I can see from `/proc/PID/smaps` that there were no anon hugepages used for the BSS after write init.

Comment: @PeterCordes - it's an implementation tradeoff. It's not easy to make a fast, low latency, low power VIPT L1 cache, so AMD uses something called "microtagging". This lets you do the L1 lookup with the V address only, moving the TLB out of the critical path. The downside is that virtual aliases are not resolved, and so you you can have only one V alias of a given P address in the cache at once.

Comment: Note for example that AMD has 4-cycle latency in many more scenarios than Intel, so that is probably one positive outcome of the design.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Interesting, thanks for the info on AMD.  I just tried `madvise(..., MADV_NOHUGEPAGE)` on my Skylake, and confirmed that Intel's VIPT cache really can give all L1d hits.  (But at the cost of more TLB misses).  https://godbolt.org/z/91cpyE run with no args for read-init, or with argc>1 for write-init. I get basically all mem loads being `mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u` for read-init.  So this confirms that Intel's design is definitely not like AMD's.

Comment: Yes, Intel's recent designs are all pure VIPT AFAIK.

Comment: @BeeOnRope IMO, the key part is **linear-address-based** microtag (utag). _The utag is a hash of the load's linear address (V)._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: seg:off to linear happens before virt(linear) to physical translation.  So yes, if you're building a cache with microtagging, you'd use linear virtual addresses, not segment:offset.  Non-zero segment bases (FS or GS) can pay the extra latency for an adder before starting the normal process.

Answer (score 6):

**Memory mapping/allocating is lazy**: the first access to a page will cause a page fault exception (`#PF` on x86).  This includes the BSS, as well as file-backed mappings like the text segment of your executable.  These page faults are "valid" so they don't result in a SIGSEGV being delivered; instead the kernel allocates a physical page if necessary and wires up the hardware page tables so the load or store can rerun and not fault the 2nd time.

This is expensive, especially if the kernel doesn't "fault-around" and prepare multiple pages during one page fault.  (Especially with Spectre + Meltdown mitigation enabled making user<->kernel round trips more expensive on current x86-64 hardware.)

You're letting `std:vector`'s constructor write zeros to the array after dynamic allocation<sup>1</sup>.  **`std::vector` does all the page-faulting outside your timed loop.**  This happens before main, while the implementation is running constructors for static objects.

But the array is zero-initialized so it gets placed in the BSS.  The first thing to touch it is your loop.  **Your `array<>` loop pays for all the page faults inside the timed region.**

If you used `new int[n]` to dynamically allocate but *not* initialize a block of memory, you'd see the same behaviour as from your static `array<>`.  (Maybe slightly better if Linux is more willing to use transparent hugepages for a dynamic allocation instead of the BSS mapping.)

---

---

**Footnote 1** `std::vector` in libstdc++ and libc++ is too stupid to take advantage of getting already-zeroed pages from the OS, like it could if it used `calloc` or equivalent.  It would be possible if the library provided a `new`/`delete`-compatible allocator for zeroed memory.

C++ `new`/`delete` is crippled vs. malloc/free/calloc/realloc.  I have no idea why ISO C++ left out calloc and realloc: both are very useful for large allocations, especially realloc for resizing a std::vector of trivially-copyable objects that might have room to grow its mapping without copying.  But since `new`/`delete` aren't guaranteed to be compatible with `malloc`/`free`, and `new` is replaceable, libraries can't very easily use `calloc` and `realloc` even under the hood.

---

#### Another factor: read-only leaves pages CoW mapped to the same physical zero page

When lazy allocation is triggered by a read (instead of write), it reads as zero.  (BSS pages read as zero, new pages from `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` read as all-zero.)

The (soft) page fault handler that wired up the HW page table didn't need to actually allocate a physical page aka page-frame to back that virtual page.  Instead, Linux maps clean (unwritten) anonymous pages to a single physical zeroed page.  (This applies across all tasks.)

If we make multiple passes over the array, this leads to the curious situation where we can get TLB misses but L1d or L3 hits (depending on hugepage or not) because we have multiple virtual pages pointing to the same physical location.

(Some CPUs, e.g. AMD Ryzen, use micro-tagging in the L1d cache to save, at the cost of the cache only being able to hit for one virtual address even if the same memory is mapped to multiple virtual addresses.  Intel CPUs use true VIPT L1d caches and really can get this effect),

I made a test program for Linux that will use `madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)` (to encourage the kernel to defrag memory for hugepages) or `madvise(MADV_NOHUGEPAGE)` (to disable hugepages even for the read-only case).

For some reason Linux BSS pages don't use hugepages when you write them.  Only reading them does use 2M hugepages (too big for L1d or L2, but does fit in L3.  But we do get all TLB hits).  It's hard to see this in `/proc/PID/smaps` because unwritten memory doesn't show up as "resident" at all.  (Remember it's physically backed by a system-wide shared region of zeroes).

**I made some changes to your benchmark code to rerun the sum loop multiple times *after* an init pass** that either reads or writes the array, according to command-line args.  The repeat-loop makes it run longer so we can get more precise timing, and to amortize the init so we get useful results from perf.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/mman.h>

using namespace std;

constexpr int n = 100'000'000;
//vector<int> v(n);
alignas(4096) array<int, n> v;

//template<class T>
__attribute__((noinline))
int toucharray(volatile int *vv, int write_init) {
        int res=vv[0];
        for(int i=32 ; i<n ; i+=128)
                if(write_init)
                    vv[i] = 0;
                else
                    res += vv[i];
//      volatile int sum = res;  // noinline is fine, we don't need to stop multiple calls from CSEing
        return res;
}

template <class T>
__attribute__((noinline,noclone))
int sum_container(T &vv) {
    unsigned int res=0;
    for(int x : vv)
        res += x;
    __attribute__((used)) static volatile int sink;
    sink = res;  // a side-effect stops IPA from deciding that this is a pure function
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int write_init = 0;
    int hugepage = 0;
    if (argc>1) {
            hugepage = argv[1][0] & 1;
            write_init = argv[1][0] & 2;
    }
    int repcount = 1000;
    if (argc>2)
            repcount = atoi(argv[2]);

// TODO: option for no madvise.
    madvise(v.data(), n*sizeof(v[0]), MADV_SEQUENTIAL);
    madvise(v.data(), n*sizeof(v[0]), hugepage ? MADV_HUGEPAGE : MADV_NOHUGEPAGE);  
    madvise(v.data(), n*sizeof(v[0]), MADV_WILLNEED); 
 // SEQ and WILLNEED probably only matter for file-backed mappings to reduce hard page faults.
 //  Probably not encouraging faultahead / around for lazy-allocation soft page fault

    toucharray(v.data(), write_init);

    int res = 0;
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int i=0; i<repcount ; i++)
        res = sum_container(v);
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    double elapsed =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<
            std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>
        >(end - start).count();
    printf("result: %d\ntime: %f\n", res, elapsed);
}
```

best case: clang++ -O3 -march=native (skylake) actually unrolls with multiple accumulators, unlike gcc -funroll-loops which does a silly job.

On my Skylake i7-6700k with DDR4-2666 DRAM, configured for 4.2GHz max turbo and governor=performance -

```
# using std::array<int,n>
# 0&1 = 0 -> MADV_NOHUGEPAGE.  0&2 = 0 -> read-only init
taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u,mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u,mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u ./touchpage-array-argc.clang 0 1000
result: 0
time: 1961.952394

 Performance counter stats for './touchpage-array-madv-nohuge-argc.clang 0 1000':

          2,017.34 msec task-clock:u              #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                50      context-switches          #    0.025 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            97,774      page-faults               #    0.048 M/sec                  
     8,287,680,837      cycles                    #    4.108 GHz                    
    14,500,762,859      instructions              #    1.75  insn per cycle         
            13,688      mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u #    0.007 M/sec                  
    12,501,329,912      mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u # 6196.927 M/sec                  
           144,559      mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u #    0.072 M/sec                  

       2.017765632 seconds time elapsed

       1.979410000 seconds user
       0.036659000 seconds sys
```

Notice considerable TLB misses (`mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u` counts 2nd-level TLB misses in user-space).  And 97k page faults.  That's pretty much exactly as many 4k pages as it takes to cover the 100M * 4 = 400MB array, so we got 1 fault per page with no pre-fault / fault-around.

Fortunately Skylake has two page-walk units so it can be doing two speculative page-walks in parallel.  Also, all the data access is hitting in L1d so page-tables will stay hot in at least L2, speeding up page walks.

```
# using array
# MADV_HUGEPAGE,  read-only init
taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u,mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u,mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u ./touchpage-array-argc.clang 1 1000
result: 0
time: 5947.741408

 Performance counter stats for './touchpage-array-argc.clang 1 1000':

          5,951.40 msec task-clock:u              #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                 9      context-switches          #    0.002 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
               687      page-faults               #    0.115 K/sec                  
    24,377,094,416      cycles                    #    4.096 GHz                    
    14,397,054,228      instructions              #    0.59  insn per cycle         
     2,183,878,846      mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u #  366.952 M/sec                  
       313,684,419      mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u #   52.708 M/sec                  
            13,218      mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u #    0.002 M/sec                  

       5.951530513 seconds time elapsed

       5.944087000 seconds user
       0.003284000 seconds sys
```

Notice ~1/10th the TLB misses, but that out of the same ~12G mem loads, only 2G of them hit in L2, probably thanks to successful HW prefetch.  (The rest did hit in L3 though.)  And that we only had 687 page faults; a combination of faultaround and hugepages made this much more efficient.

And note that the time taken is 3x higher because of the bottleneck on L3 bandwidth.

---

Write-init of the array gives us the worst of both worlds:

```
# using array
# MADV_HUGEPAGE (no apparent effect on BSS)  and write-init

taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u,mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u,mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u ./touchpage-array-argc.clang 3 1000
result: 0
time: 16510.222762

 Performance counter stats for './touchpage-array-argc.clang 3 1000':

         17,143.35 msec task-clock:u              #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
               341      context-switches          #    0.020 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            95,218      page-faults               #    0.006 M/sec                  
    70,475,978,274      cycles                    #    4.111 GHz                    
    17,989,948,598      instructions              #    0.26  insn per cycle         
       634,015,284      mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u #   36.983 M/sec                  
       107,041,744      mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u #    6.244 M/sec                  
        37,715,860      mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u #    2.200 M/sec                  

      17.147615898 seconds time elapsed

      16.494211000 seconds user
       0.625193000 seconds sys
```

Lots of page faults.  Also far more TLB misses.

#### std::vector version is basically the same as array:

`strace` shows that madvise didn't work because I didn't align the pointer.  glibc / libstdc++ `new` tends to return a pointer that page-aligned + 16, with allocator bookkeeping in that first 16 bytes.  For the array, I used `alignas(4096)` to make sure I could pass it to madvise.

`madvise(0x7f760d133010, 400000000, MADV_HUGEPAGE) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`

So anyway, with my kernel tuning settings, it only tries to defrag memory for hugepages on madvise, and memory is pretty fragmented ATM.  So it didn't end up using any hugepages.

```
taskset -c 3 perf stat -etask-clock:u,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u,mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u,mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u ./touchpage-vector-argv.clang 3 1000
result: 0
time: 16020.821517

 Performance counter stats for './touchpage-vector-argv.clang 3 1000':

         16,159.19 msec task-clock:u              #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                17      context-switches          #    0.001 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
            97,771      page-faults               #    0.006 M/sec                  
    66,146,780,261      cycles                    #    4.093 GHz                    
    15,294,999,994      instructions              #    0.23  insn per cycle         
       217,426,277      mem_load_retired.l2_hit:u #   13.455 M/sec                  
       842,878,166      mem_load_retired.l1_hit:u #   52.161 M/sec                  
         1,788,935      mem_inst_retired.stlb_miss_loads:u #    0.111 M/sec                  

      16.160982779 seconds time elapsed

      16.017206000 seconds user
       0.119618000 seconds sys
```

I'm not sure why TLB misses is so much higher than for the THP read-only test.  Maybe contention for memory access and/or eviction of cached page tables by touching more memory ends up slowing down pagewalks so TLB-prefetch doesn't keep up.

Out of the ~12G loads, HW prefetching was able to make about 1G of them hit in L1d or L2 cache.