# Fast synchronized access to shared array with changing base address (in C11)

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, scheduling, c11, stdatomic

I am currently designing a user space scheduler in C11 for a custom co-processor under Linux (user space, because the co-processor does not run its own OS, but is controlled by software running on the host CPU). It keeps track of all the tasks' states with an array. Task states are regular integers in this case. The array is dynamically allocated and each time a new task is submitted whose state does not fit into the array anymore, the array is reallocated to twice its current size. The scheduler uses multiple threads and thus needs to synchronize its data structures.

Now, the problem is that I very often need to read entries in that array, since I need to know the states of tasks for scheduling decisions and resource management. If the base address was guaranteed to always be the same after each reallocation, I would simply use C11 atomics for accessing it. Unfortunately, realloc obviously cannot give such a guarantee. So my current approach is wrapping each access (reads AND writes) with one big lock in the form of a pthread mutex. Obviously, this is really slow, since there is locking overhead for each read, and the read is really small, since it only consists of a single integer.

To clarify the problem, I give some code here showing the relevant passages:

Writing:

```
// pthread_mutex_t mut;
// size_t len_arr;
// int *array, idx, x;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
if (idx >= len_arr) {
    len_arr *= 2;
    array = realloc(array, len_arr*sizeof(int));
    if (array == NULL)
        abort();
}
array[idx] = x;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
```

Reading:

```
// pthread_mutex_t mut;
// int *array, idx;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
int x = array[idx];
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
```

I have already used C11 atomics for efficient synchronization elsewhere in the implementation and would love to use them to solve this problem as well, but I could not find an efficient way to do so. In a perfect world, there would be an atomic accessor for arrays which performs address calculation and memory read/write in a single atomic operation. Unfortunately, I could not find such an operation. But maybe there is a similarly fast or even faster way of achieving synchronization in this situation?

EDIT:
I forgot to specify that I cannot reuse slots in the array when tasks terminate. Since I guarantee access to the state of every task ever submitted since the scheduler was started, I need to store the final state of each task until the application terminates. Thus, static allocation is not really an option.

Comment: What?  So in normal operation, your array size has unbounded growth over time?  That sounds like a design problem; maybe you need synchronization points where all other threads pause for a reclaim/compact, or where they all agree that the low n pages are no longer in use (and won't ever be again), so one thread can `munmap` it to hand the pages back to the OS.

Comment: You can only statically allocate about 2GiB in the "medium" or "medium-PIC" code models on x86-64 System V (or use linker tricks to put that array as the last thing in the BSS, so the start of it is addressable with RIP-relative and 32-bit absolute, but the end isn't).  Or you can dynamically allocate a *huge* amount up front (like many TiB) so the address-space is all there if/when you need it without ever having to realloc.  Like I explained in my answer, there's very little downside to this because of lazy allocation.

Comment: Well, of course, you cannot submit an infinite amount of tasks to the scheduler, since system memory is finite. However, I find the idea of setting a firm limit a bit odd. Although, practically, I could probably set the allocation to 1GiB and the user would never submit enough tasks to exhaust that, or only due to erroneous application code, which would justify the program to crash.
Maybe I should limit the available "task state history" to the last 10k tasks submitted by the user.
Honestly, I don't know which solution to prefer. Yours is probably faster and more pragmatic.

Comment: You could log old ones to disk so you can recycle memory.  In fact, you even consider a file-backed memory mapping for this table, allowing the OS to write back pages to disk when they haven't been modified for a while.  (I think this even works for a sparse file, so you don't have to waste disk space to just make a huge allocation that you'll never practically use all of.)  Or you could keep a small circular buffer of active tasks, and append an entry from that to disk when it completes.  (Optionally only do that in-order so you can easily know where to find an entry, mem or disk.)

Comment: That's a good idea. So far, this part never used up any relevant amount of memory in my tests, though. I might add that later, though, if memory consumption becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to be so economical with virtual address space?  Can't you just **set a very big upper limit and allocate enough address space for it** (maybe even a static array, or dynamic if you want the upper limit to be set at startup from command-line options).

**Linux does lazy memory allocation so virtual pages that you never touch aren't actually using *any* physical memory**.  See [Why is iterating though `std::vector` faster than iterating though `std::array`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125253/why-is-iterating-though-stdvector-faster-than-iterating-though-stdarray/57130924#57130924) that show by example that reading or writing an anonymous page for the first time causes a page fault.  If it was a read access, it gets the kernel to CoW (copy-on-write) map it to a shared physical zero page.  Only an initial write, or a write to a CoW page, triggers actual allocation of a physical page.

Leaving virtual pages completely untouched avoids even the overhead of wiring them into the hardware page tables.

**If you're targeting a 64-bit ISA like x86-64, you have boatloads of virtual address space**.  Using up more virtual address space (as long as you aren't wasting physical pages) is basically fine.

---

#### Practical example of allocating more address virtual space than you can use:

**If you allocate more memory than you could ever practically use** (touching it all would definitely segfault or invoke the kernel's OOM killer), that will be as large or larger than you could ever grow via `realloc`.

To allocate this much, you may need to globally set `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to 1 (no checking) instead of the default `0` (heuristic which makes extremely large allocations fail).  Or **use [`mmap(MAP_NORESERVE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#DESCRIPTION) to allocate it**, making that one mapping just best-effort growth on page-faults.

The documentation says you might get a `SIGSEGV` on touching memory allocated with `MAP_NORESERVE`, which is different than invoking the OOM killer.  But I think once you've already successfully touched memory, it is yours and won't get discarded.  I think it's also not going to spuriously fail unless you're actually running out of RAM + swap space.  IDK how you plan to detect that in your current design (which sounds pretty sketchy if you have no way to ever deallocate).

Test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void) {
        size_t sz = 1ULL << 46;   // 2**46 = 64 TiB = max power of 2 for x86-64 with 48-bit virtual addresses
                                  // in practice  1ULL << 40  (1TiB) should be more than enough.
        // the smaller you pick, the less impact if multiple things use this trick in the same program

        //int *p = aligned_alloc(64, sz); // doesn't use NORESERVE so it will be limited by overcommit settings

        int *p = mmap(NULL, sz, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0);
        madvise(p, sz, MADV_HUGEPAGE);       // for good measure to reduce page-faults and TLB misses, since you're using large contiguous chunks of this array

        p[1000000000] = 1234;    // or sz/sizeof(int) - 1 will also work; this is only touching 1 page somewhere in the array.
        printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

```sh
$ gcc -Og -g -Wall alloc.c
$ strace ./a.out
...  process startup
mmap(NULL, 70368744177664, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x15c71ef7c000
madvise(0x15c71ef7c000, 70368744177664, MADV_HUGEPAGE) = 0
...  stdio stuff
write(1, "0x15c71ef7c000\n", 15) = 15
0x15c71ef7c000
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

My desktop has 16GiB of RAM (a lot of it in use by Chromium and some big files in /tmp) + 2GiB of swap.  Yet this program allocated 64 TiB of virtual address space and touched 1 `int` of it nearly instantly.  Not measurably slower than if it had only allocated 1MiB.  (And future performance from actually using that memory should also be unaffected.)

The largest power-of-2 you can expect to work on current x86-64 hardware is `1ULL << 46`.  The total lower canonical range of the 48-bit virtual address space is 47 bits (user-space virtual address space on Linux), and some of that is already allocated for stack/code/data.  Allocating a contiguous 64 TiB chunk of that still leaves plenty for other allocations.

(If you *do* actually have that much RAM + swap, you're probably waiting for a new CPU [with 5-level page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_5-level_paging) so you can use even more virtual address space.)

Speaking of page tables, the larger the array the more chance of putting some *other* future allocations very very far from existing blocks.  This can have a *minor* cost in TLB-miss (page walk) time, if your actual in-use pages end up more scattered around your address space in more [different sub-trees of the multi-level page tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-64bit-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-short-48bit-long-compared-with-the).  That's more page-table memory to keep in cache (including cached within the page-walk hardware).

The allocation size doesn't have to be a power of 2 but it might as well be.  There's also no reason to make it *that* big.  `1ULL << 40` (1TiB) should be *fine* on most systems.  IDK if having more than half the available address space for a process allocated could slow future allocations; bookkeeping is I think based on extents (ptr + length) not bitmaps.

Keep in mind that **if everyone starts doing this for random arrays in libraries**, that could use up a lot of address space.  This is great for *the* main array in a program that spends a lot of time using it.  Keep it as small as you can while still being big enough to always be more than you need.  (Optionally make it a config parameter if you want to avoid a "640kiB is enough for everyone" situation).  Using up virtual address space is very low-cost, but it's probably better to use less.

---

**Think of this as *reserving* space for future growth** but not actually using it until you touch it.  Even though by some ways of looking at it, the memory already is "allocated".  But in Linux it really isn't.  Linux defaults to allowing "overcommit": processes can have more total anonymous memory mapped than the system has physical RAM + swap.  If too many processes try to use too much by actually touching all that allocated memory, the OOM killer has to kill something (because the "allocate" system calls like `mmap` have already returned success).  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

(With `MAP_NORESERVE`, it's only reserving address space which is shared between threads, but not reserving any physical pages until you touch them.)

You probably want your array to be page-aligned:  `#include <stdalign.h>` so you can use something like
`alignas(4096) struct entry  process_array[MAX_LEN];`
Or for non-static, allocate it with C11 `aligned_alloc()`.

---

#### Give back early parts of the array when you're sure all threads are done with it

Page alignment makes it easy do the calculations to "give back" a memory page (4kiB on x86) if your array's logical size shrinks enough.  [`madvise(addr, 4096*n, MADV_FREE);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) (Linux 4.5 and later).  This is kind of like `mmap(MAP_FIXED)` to replace some pages with new untouched anonymous pages (that will read as zeroes), except it doesn't split up the logical mapping extents and create more bookkeeping for the kernel.

Don't bother with this unless you're returning multiple pages, and leave at least one page unfreed above the current top to avoid page faults if you grow again soon.  Like maybe maintain a high-water mark that you've ever touched (without giving back) and a current logical size.  If `high_water - logical_size > 16 pages` give back all page from 4 past the logical size up to the high water mark.

If you will typically be actually using/touching at least 2MiB of your array, use `madvise(MADV_HUGEPAGE)` when you allocate it to get the kernel to prefer using transparent hugepages.  This will reduce TLB misses.

(Use `strace` to see return values from your `madvise` system calls, and look at `/proc/PID/smaps`, to see if your calls are having the desired effect.)

---

If up-front allocation is unacceptable, RCU (read-copy-update) might be viable if it's read-mostly.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update.  But copying a gigantic array every time an element changes isn't going to work.

You'd want a different data-structure entirely where only small parts need to be copied.  Or something other than RCU; like your answer, you might not need the read side being *always* wait-free.  The choice will depend on acceptable worst-case latency and/or average throughput, and also how much contention there is for any kind of ref counter that has to bounce around between all threads.

---

Too bad there isn't a `realloc` variant that attempts to grow without copying so you could attempt that before bothering other threads.  (e.g. have threads with `idx>len` spin-wait on `len` in case it increases without the `array` address changing.)

Comment: Static allocation would certainly simplify the matter. Unfortunately, due to interface constraints, this is not really an option, see my edited question. Static allocation would only be viable if there was a limit to the total number of tasks which can be submitted during the scheduler's lifetime, which is not desirable.
However, you hit a point about the alignment of the management structures. I will definitely add this to my implementation.
Inspired by RCU, I came up with an efficient solution for the problem, which I will elaborate in a distinct answer.

Comment: @programonkey: I added an example with `mmap(MAP_NORESERVE)` to allocate way more memory than the computer has RAM + swap, so that's more than you could ever possibly use via realloc.

Answer (score 1):

So, I came up with a solution:

Reading:

```
while(true) {
  cnt++;
  if (wait) {
    cnt--;
    yield();
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
int x = array[idx];
cnt--;
```

Writing:

```
if (idx == len) {
  wait = true;
  while (cnt > 0);  // busy wait to minimize latency of reallocation
  array = realloc(array, 2*len*sizeof(int));
  if (!array) abort();  // shit happens
  len *= 2;  // must not be updated before reallocation completed
  wait = false;
}

// this is why len must be updated after realloc,
// it serves for synchronization with other writers
// exceeding the current length limit
while (idx > len) {yield();}

while(true) {
  cnt++;
  if (wait) {
    cnt--;
    yield();
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
array[idx] = x;
cnt--;
```

`wait` is an atomic bool initialized as false, `cnt` is an atomic int initialized as zero.
This only works because I know that task IDs are chosen ascendingly without gaps and that no task state is read before it is initialized by the write operation. So I can always rely on the one thread which pulls the ID which only exceeds current array length by 1. New tasks created concurrently will block their thread until the responsible thread performed reallocation. Hence the busy wait, since the reallocation should happen quickly so the other threads do not have to wait for too long.

This way, I eliminate the bottlenecking big lock. Array accesses can be made concurrently at the cost of two atomic additions. Since reallocation occurs seldom (due to exponential growth), array access is practically block-free.

EDIT:
After taking a second look, I noticed that one has to be careful about reordering of stores around the length update. Also, the whole thing only works if concurrent writes always use different indices. This is the case for my implementation, but might not generally be. Thus, this is not as elegant as I thought and the solution presented in the accepted answer should be preferred.

Comment: don't forget to check for `realloc` failure, unless you want to just crash in that case.  (`realloc` returns `NULL` and leaves the original memory still allocated, so this leaks, but that doesn't matter if you want to just segfault).  Could happen in 32-bit code if you run out of virtual address space, or depending on overcommit settings possibly on some 64-bit kernels.  You might also want to grow by a factor of 3 or 4 to make growth even less frequent.  You might as well make you initial allocation at least 1GiB, as long as you don't touch unused parts of that memory.

Comment: You could avoid `goto` with a more readable `while(1){ cnt++; if(!wait)break; ...; }`.  Often `do{}while()` loops are helpful but I don't see a way to use one without peeling/duplicating some of the loop body.

Comment: For x86, use `while( cnt > 0 ) _mm_pause();` for the spin-loop body to optimize spin-waiting.  (From `immintrin.h`).  Maybe `#define` a macro or an inline function for spin-loop bodies that can run `pause` on x86, or empty or something else on other ISAs.

Comment: You're right, I skipped the NULL-check in this explanation for readibility. Will edit it in.
Will also add your syntax improvement.
As you suggest, a combination of both our approaches might be the best solution here. I will thus accept your answer.

Comment: This still seems a *lot* worse than a 2 TiB or so dynamic allocation at process startup (way bigger than your can use without triggering the OOM killer, thus bigger than your realloc could ever practically reach).  Your `cnt` is close to a hand-rolled lock as far as serializing all threads accessing the array which otherwise wouldn't contend if there were accessing different cache lines.  It releases a lot quicker than an actual lock but the cache line containing it still has to ping-pong to all CPUs.

Comment: You're right, I did not consider cache coherency protocol overhead. A student has to bow to a master.

Comment: re: your edit.  Yes, of course `array` and the other variable have to be `_Atomic` integers / pointers.  But `cnt--` is a sequential-consistency decrement so it orders the non-atomic accesses to `arr[idx]`.  (If you actually *are* using `arr` more than once, you'd want `entry_type *tmparr = array;` and then use that local.  Otherwise you get a seq-cst reload of `arr` for every `array[idx].a = whatever`.  (Compilers currently don't optimize atomics basically at all, and the default sequential-consistency memory order is very strong).

Comment: I had another thought about your refcounting (in case it proves useful for some future readers that can't just overallocate): it can in theory livelock because threads keep incrementing `cnt` while spin-waiting for `!wait`.  In practice `yield()` probably sleeps long enough unless you have way too many total threads, even when there are no other threads to run so it returns in this thread right away.  But really after finding `wait` is true, you should decrement `cnt` once and then not touch it until a read-only `while(wait) yield();` loop ends.  Then redo the normal cnt++ / check wait / ...

Comment: And BTW, instead of rolling your own `yield()` loop, use a condition variable so the thread doing a realloc can wake all the others efficiently with OS-assisted sleep/wakeup.  And so it doesn't have other threads loading `wait` from (probably) the same cache line as `len` and `array`, potentially slowing down committing those stores.

Comment: Anyway, refcounting on every access all is still pretty bad; you might consider an array of per-thread variables (with 32-byte spacing or something so only pairs of threads share a cache line for a tradeoff between write and read efficiency).  Ideally with hyperthread siblings sharing a cache line on the same physical core, but that's impractical unless you do thread-affinity.  Anyway, instead of a count the reader can wait until all array elements are 0.  That scan only has to happen when realloc is needed, with `wait=1`.  Otherwise threads are just setting/clearing their private entry.

Comment: Or another option: if every thread participating does something to the array regularly, you can leave the refcnt incremented across calls until you see `wait` set.  Only *then* do you decrement, wait on the condition variable, and increment it again.  That increases the worst-case latency for reallocation by a lot, though: if a thread is does read or write the array for a few seconds, the others that are trying to read or write are stuck.